# How should I use Critical Section?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have problem where I should place CriticalSection. In thread I have public procedure (write) where I write data in file.

Should I use CriticalSection in this procedure or in every thread when I call this procedure?

Example:

I have a thread and I create CS.

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  CS:TCriticalSection;
  public
    procedure Write(msg:string);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create;
  end;


constructor TMyThread.Create;
begin
CS.TCriticalSection.Create;
end;
```

And my question. Where use CS?

There:

```
procedure TMyThread.Write(msg:string);
begin
  CS.Enter;
  { WRITING IN FILE msg }
  CS.Leave;
end;
```

or in every thread?

```
CS.Enter;
MyThread.Write('cos');
CS.Leave;
```

Comment: Strange to see a critical section created in a thread constructor; critical sections synchronize different thread instances, it is not clear how you are going to use your critical section.

Comment: So I ask how to use critical section :)

Comment: Did you even google?

Comment: It's important to understand that critical sections are intended to protect _data_ (not code). You need a clear understanding of what your code is doing so you know when multiple threads can potentially access shared ***data***. (The data can be in memory or in files; the principal is the same either way.) If the same code always accesses different objects from different threads, you don't need critical sections. If different code accesses the same objects from a single thread, you still don't need critical sections. You only need them for multiple threads using the ***same*** objects/data.

Comment: When you ***do need*** critical sections, each object needing protection must be protected by a ***single*** critical section (otherwise there's no protection at all). Also, you need to ensure you enter the critical ***before*** you start using the ***data*** from _everywhere_ that can access the data. However, this is where understanding the distinction between protecting data vs code is important. You can localise entering critical inside the method that actually touches the data because `CS.Enter` is _just code_! This very importantly avoids huge amounts of repetitive code.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is written on the assumption that each thread writes to a single common file. Hence the need for synchronization. If, as you intimate in the comments, each thread writes to a different file, then no synchronization is needed.

---

You have quite a few problems with your code. You need to have a one to one mapping between instances of the critical section, and protected objects. Here you have one critical section per thread which serves no purpose at all. No serialization will be performed by your code.

Since you are protecting access to a single file, you need to have a single instance of the critical section object. Each thread must have access to that single shared critical section object. Some options:

1. Pass the critical section object to the thread and arrange for the consumers of the thread to manage the critical section object's lifetime.
2. Declare the critical section object as a global variable in the implementation section of the unit that declares the thread. Create and destroy the object in the unit's initialization and finalization sections.
3. Declare the critical section object as a class variable in the thread. Create and destroy the object in class constructor and class destructor.
4. Move the critical section and the log writing into a dedicated logging class.

Beyond that, the constructor for your thread is broken. You have to call the inherited constructor in order for the thread object to be properly created.

Given all those changes, either of the options you propose for using the critical section will function correctly. However, it is clearly much better to acquire the lock inside `Write`. That way it is impossible to call the function without acquiring the lock. The code to acquire the lock only has to be written once.

Comment: So I can use CS only inside this one procedure where I write and any other threads can use this procedure and everything will be ok?
I ask because others threads will not 'see' this CS.

Comment: The other threads do see it. Threads execute code, and when those threads call the function, they can see the section.

Comment: @MBo You are right, there are many other problems too with the code. I did not study it closely enough. I will update.

Comment: So... can I create global array and put there every CS for each thread?

Comment: No. There needs to be exactly one critical section that every thread shares, assuming that each thread writes to the same file. If each thread writes to a different file then you don't need to synchronize at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to write to a single file from several threads you should share the same critical section among all these threads, and this means that you normally should create a critical section instance elsewhere and pass it in the thread constructor, for example

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCS:TCriticalSection;
  public
    procedure Write(msg:string);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create(ACS: TCriticalSection);
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(ACS: TCriticalSection);
begin
  inherited Create;  // don't forget to call inherited constructor
  FCS:= ACS;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Write(msg:string);
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  { WRITING IN FILE msg }
  FCS.Leave;
end;
```

Comment: And if every thread has own file and other thread besides write in his file want write in other 'threads files'? This is what I want achieve

Comment: then you would need a mechanism to choose the correct critical section for each file - in each thread. (if I understand you correctly) It may be that `synchronize` is a more convenient mechanism for you than `TCriticalSection`